# Renaming a file in php

Tags: php, bash

I'm getting a permission denied error when trying to run the `rename` command in PHP.

The file it is trying to rename is in another users home directory.

Here's what I've done so far:

Given the PHP user (userA) access to that group.  So when I run `id`
    I get 
`uid=1004(userA) gid=1006(userA) groups=1006(userA),10(wheel),1007(userB)`

The PHP script is running as `userA`.

I ran `sudo chmod -R g+rwx ./*` in from the `/home/userB/subdomains/mp3s` directory.

When I navigate to the directory where the files are kept, under `/home/userB/subdomains/mp3s/` and run `ls -lha` I get:
`-rw-rwxr-- 1 userB userB  62M Aug  8  2017 Stress Management - Lesson 1.mp3`

So the group has permission to read/write/execute, and my `userA` has access to that group, so why can't it rename the file?

Comment: Are you sure you're in the right directory, and that the path to the file is correct?

Comment: What operating system is this on?

Comment: @CurtisKelsey CentOS

Comment: @TomFenech yes I am

Comment: You need to verify that folder where files are located (/home/userB/subdomains/mp3s) has also correct ownership and permissions. To rename a file you need write permissions to folder.

Comment: @voter Does that include *all* folders in its parent? or just the immediate parent folder of the file?

Comment: Just folder where file is located. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/272225/minimum-file-permissions-to-rename-file

Comment: @voter This is what the parent directory of the file looks like: `drwxrwxr-x 2 userB userB  20K Mar 13 13:23`

Comment: Then it is not the reason. I have no other ideas :(

Comment: I can rename it from the command line, using sudo.  But not as `userA`. :(

Answer (score 1):

So I am betting you got SELinux with that fancy CentOS instance. Add the following on top of your permission changes to allow PHP to rename files:

```
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /home/userB/subdomains/mp3s/ -R
```

The command may need different permissions for PHP CLI as opposed to the web service operating against it but you can find information on that on the CentOS SELinux how to:

https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux

The first command helped me and was found on:

https://blog.lysender.com/2015/07/centos-7-selinux-php-apache-cannot-writeaccess-file-no-matter-what/